# Configure DNS Azure to multiples sites in VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-dns

I have VM for development in Azure w/ azure provided static public IP address. DNS name label for public IP is lets say "aaa". It is assigned to VM and a web site hosted in this VM is accessible as http:\aaa.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com w/o any issues.

However, I need a second and third web site, which again will be hosted in same VM and needs to be accessible as http:\bbb.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com and http:\ccc.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com

All are configured to listen on port 80 on the ISS of VM.

In summary how can make aaa, bbb and ccc to point to same public IP address in Azure?

Comment: What is the web server? For Apache, use VirtualHost records. Nginx has similar features. You can then host as many sites are your server has capacity. There are many articles on configuring web servers for multiple domains on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

***To configure DNS azure to multiple sites in VM. you can make Azure support customers to map multiple domain names to one VM.***

Before trying to map multiple domain names to one Azure VM, try to create company1.yourdomaihn.com as [CNAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)

Try to point the CNAME to the DNS Domain Label  of your  [public ip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#public-ip-addresses)

- log in to your account at your domain name
- In my account -> click domain ->advanced technical setting ->click edit domain aliases record -> enter the name/ host/alias from CNAME
- In second field -> enter value / answer /destination from the  CName  -> continue -> create

you can add multiple domain names to one public IP address

[image]

You can check some document [Host Multiple Sites from ONE Azure IIS Server (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/68975261-2a6f-48bc-8526-f8887f0df99f/host-multiple-sites-from-one-azure-iis-server?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows)